# How to retrieve the original file path of a resource in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

You can use the following the get the path of a file that's part of the compiled application's bundle:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"txt"];
// .../iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/52AD3E56-41DC-4A0E-A435-DACBF9475540/MyApp/MyFile.txt
```

But is there a way to get the path of the original file, within the Xcode project's directory?

For the above example, it would be something like `~/projects/xcode/MyApp/MyFile.txt`.

Here's the context: I'm working on a project ([NUI](https://github.com/tombenner/nui)) and want to be able to run the application, modify a resource's file in Xcode while the app is running, then re-read the newly modified file in the app while the app is still running.

This would only be used during development. Is this isn't explicitly possible, does anyone have any ideas of other approaches to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Resource files (MyFiles.txt in your case) are sandboxed inside the application. You can access them at the runtime from inside the app itself using mainBundle pathForResource as you already mention. But once the application bundle is created, there is no question of accessing that file from Xcode, because the application uses MyFile.txt which is inside the bundle and not the one you have added in your Xcode project. So in simple terms, when your app is running, it is not accessing the txt file inside your Xcode. This txt file is a part of app itself which is inside the application bundle.

Now the question about - **can you access this file from app** - AFAIK, No you cannot do that.

Comment: I had read that this was the case, but `[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/my/project/MyFile.txt"]` successfully returns the file's contents, so accessing the file seems to not be an issue. The question of how to get that path remains, though.